# Цикл в Android

Tags: java, android

Нужно по нажатию одной кнопки выполнять get/post запрос, парсить текст и выводить его в textview. У меня после вывода "1" ничего не происходит, кнопка так и остается disabled. В чем проблема и как нужно правильно это реализовать ?

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
        button.setEnabled(false);
        url = editText.getText().toString();
        textView.setText("1");

        hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
        get = new HttpGet(url);
        res = hc.execute(get, rh);
        hc.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        textView.setText("2");

        m = p1.matcher(res);
        textView.setText(m.group(1));
        button.setEnabled(true);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Фигню какую-то делаете =) тут надо дебажить, вынести из онКлика инициализацию классов, проверить подключение.

Comment: :S
А как вообще это НУЖНО реализовывать при помощи apache httpclient (get/post request) ?

Comment: в onClick нужно указывать, например, метод getReq(), в котором и будет происходить инициализация hc, get ?

Comment: обработчик нажатия кнопки может быть какой хочешь, в андроиде, если не ошибаюсь, 3я способами можно делать, что и как тебе с апачем делать надо - я не знаю, я просто советую вынести логику отдельно.

 hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
        get = new HttpGet(url);

вот это куда-то "повыше",


 res = hc.execute(get, rh);
        hc.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

вот это в отдельный метод

Comment: Okay. Просто я, вот, сейчас уже нашел processes and threads android, там вроде как нужно еще отдельный поток создавать для таких действий, которые происходят в бекграунде, не?
Меня интересует именно то, как писать правильно, рационально, а не лишь бы работало.

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/124484/
"Суть статьи — работа с потоками и понимание в каких методах AsyncTask можно использовать UI поток, а в каких нет." У меня та же проблема ? Я выполняю http request в UI нитке !?

Comment: юай-ниткой порадовал =), короче, Сервисом лучше пользоваться, если, у тебя задача без интерфейса, если твой поток("нитка =) "), как то должен взаимодействовать с интерфейсом - тогда лучше АсинхТаск. Конечно же, операции с всякими там подключениями и тд лучше делать в асинхТаске

Answer (score 2):

Так делать не приветствуется... Коннекты и проч. дела надо уводить от UI треда и выносить либо в отдельный `Thread`, либо же делать через `AsyncTask` (что в общем то одно и то же).

Неплохой мануал по работе с тредами в Android [здесь](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)

Comment: Спасибо большое, это и хотел услышать.